# WPF UserControl with text conversion features: Issues with losing Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I wanted to create a UserControl with a read-only TextBox. The user can control text formatting by choosing a conversion type and scaling. I made it work, but I encountered some behavior that I don't understand.

This is how I use LockBox control in the parent window:

```xml
<local:LockBox
    Text="{Binding Counter, Mode=OneWay}"
    Scale="{Binding Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
    Conversion="{Binding Conversion, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

And LockBox code.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="demo.LockBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:demo"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Name="LockBoxUC"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <TextBox x:Name="textBox"
             Text="{Binding ElementName=LockBoxUC,
                    Path=Text,
                    Mode=OneWay}"
             Width="150"
             IsReadOnly="True"/>

</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class LockBox : UserControl {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(double), typeof(LockBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, (d,e) => { }, CoerceText));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Scale", typeof(double), typeof(LockBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(1.0, OnChange));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ConversionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Conversion", typeof(ConversionType), typeof(LockBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(ConversionType.None, OnChange));

    public double Text {
        get => (double)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
    public double Scale {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScaleProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScaleProperty, value);
    }
    public ConversionType Conversion {
        get => (ConversionType)GetValue(ConversionProperty);
        set => SetValue(ConversionProperty, value);
    }

    private double _savedValue = 0;

    public LockBox() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I tried an approach with conversion in code-behind.

```cs
private static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object baseValue) {
    var box = (LockBox)d;

    box._savedValue = (double)baseValue;
    return box.Convert((double)box._savedValue);
}

private static void OnChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var box = (LockBox)d;
    box.Text = box._savedValue;
}
```

Doing so I found some strange behavior that I don't understand. Inside OnChange, I need to set box.Text to trigger CoerceText and convert the value. The problem is, if this line executes, I can no longer update Text. The counter binding stops working. I had to change it to TwoWay mode `Text="{Binding Counter, Mode=TwoWay}"`. Why does it work like that? I also thought that setting TwoWay mode would affect the Counter value, but it doesn't.

I know if something doesn’t work in WPF, it’s probably because I shouldn’t do it, so I will use converters but I would like to know what was the cause of my problem.

Comment: The statement `box.Text = box._savedValue;` replaces a OneWay Binding of the Text property. A TwoWay Binding would be kept. As a note, a `double` property named `Text` looks odd. Text is usually supposed to be a string.